# Android service does not work

Tags: java, android

I am tryign to make a simple service. This is to learn how to create services. In my code when I click start button then it does show me the toast that says service started but when I click stop button then it does not show me toast which says service stopped. I am not getting any error in my logcat as well. Here is my code

```
package com.zafar.batterynotify;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BatteryNotify extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BatteryService.class));
        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BatteryService.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

service class

```
package com.zafar.batterynotify;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BatteryService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestory() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void onDestory() { ...
                  ^^
```

You have a typo. Please see: [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why), this is one of the reasons why you should use the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Add the following line in manifest file:

```
<service  android:enabled="true"  android:name=".BatteryService " />
```

2) Clean your project